# Espruino - connect to websocket server using domain address ex: ws://someapp.herokuapp.com

Tags: node.js, websocket, esp8266

I have already successfully connect to websocket server using IP address and port

```
function initsocket(){
  console.log('initsocket');
  var host = "120.188.xxx.xxx"; //its vps address
  var WebSocket = require("ws");
      var ws = new WebSocket(host,{
        path: '/',
        port: 5000, // default is 80
        protocol : "echo-protocol", // websocket protocol name (default is none)
        protocolVersion: 13, // websocket protocol version, default is 13
        origin: 'Espruino',
        keepAlive: 60
      });

  ws.on('open', function() {
    console.log("Connected to server");
  });

  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log("MSG: " + msg);
  });

}
```

---

*** STuCK HERE***

But still stuck(no respond) when use domain address like

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://ininodeku.herokuapp.com/');
ws.on('open', function() {
    console.log('opened');
});
ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
});
```

But that still work when using native Node.js and not in espruino

Comment: Stack? Do you mean stuck?

Comment: @gre_gor yess.. sorry my bad

Comment: hi , have you found a solution?

Comment: Anything on this? I'm dealing with the same issue currently and haven't found any solution.